# I use a shell script to count network traffic through the /proc/net/dev file on centos8, and the output is wrong

Tags: linux, shell, centos8

The following command outputs the result to 11.txt, the two lines of data are different

```
for i in 1 2;do cat /proc/net/dev | grep ens192 | awk '{print $2,$10}';sleep 1;done | tee 11.txt
more 11.txt
12713332 1377679
12713572 1377845
```

But when I put this output as a variable, the value in the second column of the file is the same

```
a=$(for i in 1 2;do cat /proc/net/dev | grep ens192 | awk '{print $2,$10}';sleep 1;done | tee 11.txt)
[root@rhel84-it ~]# more 11.txt
12748416 1403887
12748656 1403887
```

Comment: BTW, there's never a reason to do `cat foo | grep bar | awk '{baz}'`. Just do `awk '/bar/ {baz}' <foo` -- one executable instead of three.

Comment: ...that said... why should we believe that there was network traffic through this interface in the relevant direction in the second between the two samples? That is to say, what proof do we have that the output isn't _correct_ for the point in time when you measured it?